# One on One relation SQL, so one field can be NOT NULL without having to fill it out when you fill the other table

Tags: sql, relational-database

So having a one on one relationship between 2 tables. They could perfectly fine be combined into one, except for the fact you want to fill in one of the fields later, but you can't keep it "null", it's either there or it is not.

EDIT: I've been taught that a One on One relation is never okay to use and can't be justified in any case. Currenlty I'm making a database for matches and you have to guess the results. I got the results seperate from the match table because it's easier because the match results can be NOT NULL then. Loading a Dataset with the database and I don't want NULL values in the dataset.

Can I use a one on one relation in SQL? Is there a easier way?

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is?

Comment: I don't think a 1-to-1 relationship in SQL Is necessarily bad.  There's plenty of cases where you might want to do that.

Comment: Your 2nd sentence is unintelligible, please explain more clearly, use more words. Please show your current table definitions.